# How to login/sign up user with Parse Server?

Tags: node.js, parse-platform

I am attempting to login/sign up a user server side but I can't figure out how to? do I just save the sessionToken in a cookie?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `Parse.User.logIn(username, password)`. This will login the user and return a User in the success callback. The returned User will have a `sessionToken` that you can return to the client using `user.getSessionToken()`.

On future calls, you need to use the user's `sessionToken` or the `masterKey` in order to access / edit that user, hence why you should return the `sessionToken` to the client and have them pass it in the header with every API call.